# How can I instantiate a dictionary in Javascript where all keys map to the same value?

Tags: javascript, arrays, ecmascript-6, arrow-functions

I have an array like:

```
let arr = ['ABC', 'DEF']
```

And I'd like to transform that array to

```
let obj = {"ABC": 0, "DEF": 0}
```

What's the appropriate ES6 syntax to make that transformation?

```
let arr = ['ABC', 'DEF']
arr.reduce(x => ({[x] : 0 }))
```

This is close but I end up with `{"ABC": 0}`

Basically, I want to take an array of arbitrary length and assign all of the values in that array to a "default" value of 0.

Thanks!

Comment: The reduce needs to return a modified accumulator otherwise, it is writing over it each iteration

Comment: That title is awful. Change it to "keys that map to the same value."

Comment: Thanks @Dave, updated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just use a plain, simple loop:

```
const arr = ['ABC', 'DEF'];
const obj = {};
for (const x of arr) obj[x] = 0;
```

If you want to get fancy, I'd recommend [`Object.fromEntries`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/fromEntries):

```
Object.fromEntries(arr.map(x => [x, 0]))
```

Answer (score 0):

You are just making single objects like map. You need to keep returning the object.

```js
const arr = ['ABC', 'DEF']
const result = arr.reduce((o, k)  => ({[k] : 0, ...o }), {});
console.log(result)



const result2 = arr.reduce((o, k)  => (o[k] = 0, o), {});
console.log(result2)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
obj = arr.reduce((result, item, index) => {
  result[item] = 0
  return result
}, {})
```

Hopefully, this will help you. let me know if you have any issues.

Answer (score 0):

You can just use `Array.reduce` and pass an empty object as the initial value like code below:

```js
var arr = ["ABC","DEF"].reduce((a,b)=> (a[b]=0,a),{});
console.log(arr);
```